# Autocomplete text in android?

Tags: android

In my application I am using an auto-complete-text. When the user types **t** it shows **Three** , **Two** , **fifty** but I want to show **Two** , **Three** not fifty. Can any one help me to solve this problem.

```
String search[] = {"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","fifty"};    

ArrayAdapter<String> adp= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.searchtext, search);
    search_item.setThreshold(1);
    search_item.setAdapter(adp);
```

Comment: ideally you shot set the threshold to 2-3 not 1, this will cause to show up too much and waste a lot of processing time.

Comment: You need to make your custom adpter with filter

Comment: @Pragnani how to use custom adpter with filter.

Comment: @Yugesh Search the same in google, you'll find lot of tutorials and also lot of questions in SO

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i don't think you have to create custom adapter. its default functionality which you want. check this

here i have array like:

```
private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] { "Belgium",
        "France", "France_", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain","abcf","FFa","FFb","bFF","aFF" };
```

when i search ff then its give me only `2("FFa","FFb")` suggestion not `4("FFa","FFb","bFF","aFF")`

[image]

**i have used this in ActionBar. you can also use this in layout. because its  custom layout in ActionBar.**

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] { "Belgium",
        "France", "France_", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain","abcf","FFa","FFb","bFF","aFF" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        // actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        // actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_search);

        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.test, null);

        actionBar.setCustomView(v);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
        AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        textView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

test.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Action Bar:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >

        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**in Kotlin:**

I use data-binding for initials views

**xml:**

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInput_type"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/type">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/act_type"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/light"
                android:ems="10"
                android:editable="false"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**Fragment :**

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    var orderType = arrayOf("فروش", "خرید")
    lateinit var mBinding: MyFragment

    override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    mBinding = MyFragment.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val adapter= ArrayAdapter(requireContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, orderType.toList())
    mBinding.autoOrderType.threshold = 0
    mBinding.autoOrderType.setAdapter(adapter)
    return mBinding.root
}
```